# Parameter 0 of constructor in '.service ' required a bean of type '.model ' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a spring boot application, it' used to filting bad word. Where in any client can submit the request, these request can be GET,POST

But while creating this application, I am getting the following errors:
[image]

The structure of my application is:

[image]

**Model.WordFilter**

```
package com.Website.Step2.model;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import static javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class WordFilter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Word is required")
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    private User user;
}
```

**WordFilterService**

```
package com.Website.Step2.service;
import com.Website.Step2.dto.WordFilterDto;
import com.Website.Step2.mapper.WordFiterMapper;
import com.Website.Step2.model.WordFilter;
import com.Website.Step2.repository.WordFilterRepository;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import java.util.List;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor

public class WordFilterService {
    private final WordFilterRepository wordFilterRepository;
    private final WordFiterMapper wordFiterMapper;
    private final AuthService authService;
    public WordFilterDto save(WordFilterDto wordFilterDto) {
        WordFilter save = wordFilterRepository.save(wordFiterMapper.mapDtoToWordFilter(wordFilterDto, authService.getCurrentUser()));
        wordFilterDto.setId(save.getId());
        return wordFilterDto;
    }
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<WordFilterDto> getAll() {
        return wordFilterRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(wordFiterMapper::mapWordFilterToDto)
                .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

I know that many questions with the following error, are already been asked, but still I am not able to solve this.

Comment: Try tagging your WordFilterService with the @Service from "import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;"

Comment: The error message doesn't fit to the code that you posted. Do you have any other code in WordFilterService, that you have left out here?

Comment: That's all i have sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved. I just copyed all the WordFilter to another folder and deleted all the WordFilter.And i pasted it again. And it working.